# Xml Schema: How to define a key / keyref for different elements in same group?

Tags: xsd, relation

I have this part of my xsd:

```
<!-- FIELDGROUP - groups all available field types -->
<xsd:group name="FieldGroup">
    <xsd:choice id="fieldset-fields">
        <xsd:element name="TextField" type="textfield-type" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="NumberField" type="numberfield-type" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="Button" type="button-type" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:group>
```

All of those element types (textfield-type, numberfield-type, button-type) extend the common type `field-type`:

```
<!-- Fieldset -> FIELD-TYPE: the base type of all possible field elements -->
<xsd:complexType id="field-type" name="field-type" abstract="true" mixed="false">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Label" type="label-type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:group ref="FieldValidationGroup" />
    </xsd:sequence>

    <xsd:attribute id="field-type-id" name="id" type="id-type" use="required" />
    <xsd:attribute id="field-type-css-class" name="css-class" use="optional" type="css-class-type" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

I now want to create a Key that is unique among all elements directly within the `FieldGroup` - no matter which element they actually are, and be able to reference them from some elements in the `FieldValidationGroup`.

Or: how can I define the key on the `field-type` so that it is derived to all other elements extending the field-type?

As you can see I currently have an ID there, but the ID is also unique among all other elements not in the field group and that could lead to wrong references.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your general approach that relies on reuse - through xsd:group and type hierarchies -  I infer that you want to be able to "reuse" key definitions as well. If true, then the short answer is it cannot be done. *key*, *keyref*, and *unique* a.k.a *identity constraint definition schema components*, can only be nested within element declarations. One cannot define a key related to a xsd:group so that it'll work "no matter which elements they actually are", nor  "define a key" on a type "so that is is derived to all other elements."

Comment: Sad that it is not possible to do such a thing. It would feel intuitive to be able to do so.